# Spreadsheet formula

Tags: sql, regex, excel

I have a client with a large database of entries that need sorting.

In short, I have two tables I'm working with, they are in excel but i can import them into MySQL if I need to.

**Table 1 Columns (List of apartments).**

```
Owner ID
--------
     350
     350
       1
     169
     169
```

**Table 2 Columns (List of apartment owners).**

```
Owner ID | Owner Name
---------|-----------
     350 | Foo
       1 | Bar
     169 | Foorbar
```

Now I can either sit and do a search and replace for well over 1100 apartment listings but Im guessing that there is a regex or formulea out there that can basically search and replace all the ID's in the Table 1 apartments list and match them up to their owner name in Table 2.

The purpose of this is to ensure that when the CSV import to the new website happens, the apartment owner is saved as the Owners name, not the ID.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).

Comment: Ok, cool function, seems to be working, however. I have around 100 entries in my spreadsheet but my formula is increasing with every row. 
=VLOOKUP(A2,F2:G299,2,0)
=VLOOKUP(A3,F3:G300,2,0)
Now obviously I want the first cell to increase but not the range.

Comment: Lock the look up range with $ absolute reference indicators.`=VLOOKUP(A2, $F$2:$G$299, 2, FALSE)`

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks. You’ve answered my question. =VLOOKUP(A4,$F$2:$G$299,2,0)

Answer (score 0):

you can use vlookup: `=Vlookup(Table1[@Owner_ID],Table2[[Owner ID]:[Owner Name]],2,0)`

[click me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-rhoTF8SjY) to see a video to see vlookup